# i got errors when i try to install a vuetify project via npm

Tags: npm, vuejs2, npm-install, vuetify.js, npm-request

1. i followed these in the process of installation of a vuetify project:

   ```
   -npm install -g vue-cli 
   -vue init vuetifyjs/webpack my-project
   ```
2. here is the result among all errors displayed:

   ```
   -npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...","eslint":"^1.3.1","'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the npm cache.

try with

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm install -g vue-cli
3. vue init vuetifyjs/webpack my-project